# It is possible to restrict Class<?> with annotation classes?

Tags: java

Lets suppose I have two annotation classes: Annotation1 and Annotation2.

and I have a method:

```
public void doSomethingWithAnnodation(Class<?> annotationClass) {
...
}
```

The problem with this method is that any class can be passed as argument. Can I make compiler to allow only annotation classes (Annotation1 and Annotation2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify [`java.lang.annotation.Annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html), which all annotations implement, as an upper bound:

```java
public void doSomethingWithAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass) {
  //...
}
```